# Como referenciar a variável dentro do HTML através de AngularJS?

Tags: html, angularjs, controller

Dentro de um ng-controller, quero que apareça uma variável, e não está aparecendo. Código HTML:

```html
<div class="body" ng-controller="mercadoriaCarrinho as merc">
<span>Total dos produtos: {{merc.listaDoCarrinho.mercadoria.total}}</span> 
</div>
```

código AngularJS:

```html
<script> angular.module('meumodulo',[])

.controller('mercadoriaCarrinho', function ($rootScope, $http){
$rootScope.listaDoCarrinho=[];
$rootScope.mercadoria = {
 id: 'id',
 setor: 'setor',
 foto: 'foto',
 descr: 'descr',
 de: de,
 por: por,
 mercadoria: '0',
 quantidade: 0,
 total: '5',
 boto: -1
}

$rootScope.listaDoCarrinho.push($rootScope.mercadoria);
});
```

Comment: Amigo, uma observação: Na ultima linha vc declarou .push($rootScope.mercadoria0); mas dua variável é rootScope.mercadoria.

Comment: Obrigado pelo aviso, foi um erro de digitação. Está $rootScope.mercadoria0 e não estou conseguindo mesmo assim...

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está utilizando o `$rootScope` no `html`. O ideal é não utilizar `$rootScope` e sim o `this` para compartilhar dados com a `view`. Você também está usando o `push` no `array`, portanto não pode acessar sua variável pelo nome, e sim por uma posição. Altere seu `controller` para o seguinte:

```
angular
  .module('meumodulo',[])
  .controller('MercadoriaCarrinhoController', MercadoriaCarrinhoController);

MercadoriaCarrinhoController.$inject = ['$http'];

function MercadoriaCarrinhoController($http){
  var vm = this;

  vm.listaDoCarrinho = {};
  _iniciar();

  function _iniciar() {
    var mercadoria = {
      id: 'id',
      setor: 'setor',
      foto: 'foto',
      descr: 'descr',
      de: de,
      por: por,
      mercadoria: '0',
      quantidade: 0,
      total: '5',
      boto: -1
    }

    vm.listaDoCarrinho.mercadoria = mercadoria;
  }
}
```

E a `div` no seu `html`:

```
<div class="body" ng-controller="MercadoriaCarrinhoController as vm">
  <span>Total dos produtos: {{vm.listaDoCarrinho.mercadoria.total}}</span> 
</div>
```

---

Se quiser manter a implementação por `array` altere sua implementação para o seguinte:

```
angular
  .module('meumodulo',[])
  .controller('MercadoriaCarrinhoController', MercadoriaCarrinhoController);

MercadoriaCarrinhoController.$inject = ['$http'];

function MercadoriaCarrinhoController($http){
  var vm = this;

  vm.listaDoCarrinho = [];
  _iniciar();

  function _iniciar() {
    var mercadoria = {
      id: 'id',
      setor: 'setor',
      foto: 'foto',
      descr: 'descr',
      de: de,
      por: por,
      mercadoria: '0',
      quantidade: 0,
      total: '5',
      boto: -1
    }

    vm.listaDoCarrinho.push(mercadoria);
  }
}
```

E a `div` no seu `html`:

```
<div class="body" ng-controller="MercadoriaCarrinhoController as vm">
  <span>Total dos produtos: {{vm.listaDoCarrinho[0].total}}</span> 
</div>
```

---

Utilize o `vm` apenas para as variáveis que você necessita que sejam impressas na tela, caso contrário utilize `var`.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, quando você faz o push a sua variável fica assim:

```
[{"id":"id","setor":"setor","foto":"foto","descr":"descr","de":"de","por":"por","mercadoria":"0","quantidade":0,"total":"5","boto":-1}]
```

para que se possa exibir o total a forma de acesso será;

```
 total:{{merc.listaDoCarrinho[0]['total']}}
```